# Could not connect to mongodb server

Tags: mongodb, client-server

I have mongodb server. When I try to connect to it with mongoclient from first machine I cannot connect to server but at the same time when I try to connect to mongodb server from second machine I can access database successfully.

I am getting following error from first machine

```
QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server xxxxxxx:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:240:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I am having verson 3.6 of mongodb on all the server's.

Comment: connections errors can happen due to firewall blockage.check that perhaps

Comment: How do I check those blockage?

Answer (score 0):

Delete this file and then launch mongo service: `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`

Comment: Is this a question? You should phrase this to look more like an answer.